# Error while trying to run postgresql using homebrew

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I get this error after running

```
brew services start postgresql
```

```js
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5.
```

Comment: This page has the solution to your problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429012/homebrew-cant-start-service-get-bootstrap-failed-5-input-output-error-pos